# TXT file to Excel columns

Tags: excel, data-conversion

I have a txt file with information of 1031 companies. I need to get them into Excel table with header Names **NAME- Address-CONTACT-TEL-FAX-MOB-WEB-EMAIL**. Since there are 1031 companies I don't want to do it one by one. What is the easiest way to get them all in an Excel table?

```
"Company Name"
"Address ; XXXXXXXXX"
"Contact ; XYXYXYXYX"   
"Tel ; 1234567"
"Fax ; 123456"  
"Mob ; 12345555"
"Web ;www.www.com"  
"E-Mail ;xxxx@xx.com"
```

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I don't think ussing the Convertion assitant is easy here as the data are not even consistenly formated. I think those would be easier http://stackoverflow.com/a/26685357/6560478.

Comment: I open a version of the text in Notepadd++ or Something similar, and start a string remplacement to make this a csv. The fact that you know exactly how many compagnies you have make it easy.

Comment: Please roll back to the original version of the data.

Comment: May you revert your question to the original. This update make both answer invalid. this should have best been a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Introduction

> In this answer I will explain how to transphorm your data into a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
>    Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by semi colon as comma is often use as decimal separator.

So at the end the information will look like:

```
Company Name;XXXXXXXXX;XYXYXYXYX;1234567;123456;12345555;;xxxx@xx.com
Company Name;XXXXXXXXX;XYXYXYXYX;1234567;123456;12345555;www.www.com;xxxx@xx.com
Company Name;XXXXXXXXX;XYXYXYXYX;1234567;123456;12345555;www.www.com;xxxx@xx.com
```

or

```
"Company Name"; "XXXXXXXXX"; "XYXYXYXYX"; "1234567"; "123456"; "12345555"; ""; "xxxx@xx.com"
"Company Name"; "XXXXXXXXX"; "XYXYXYXYX"; "1234567"; "123456"; "12345555"; "www.www.com"; "xxxx@xx.com"
"Company Name"; "XXXXXXXXX"; "XYXYXYXYX"; "1234567"; "123456"; "12345555"; "www.www.com"; "xxxx@xx.com"
```

Using "" encapsulate text is your choice depending on your data. because Csv rules say:

> 1/. Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted.
>   `1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"`
>   2/. Each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a pair of double-quote characters.
>   `1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"`
>   3/. Fields with embedded line breaks must be quoted (however, many CSV implementations do not support embedded line breaks).
>   `1997,Ford,E350,"Go get one now
>   they are going fast"`

### How to know if i need to encapsule a field?

Use the count function of your editor, and count `"` ,`;` check for carriage return in adress could be a good thing too. If there is none, no need to encapsulate ᕕ(ᐛ)ᕗ

### Formating process

I will choose to encapsulate all Field so I won't have to bother with Stupid Data. We will here remplace every "header" of your original data by `;`. 
To make every information  about a company in one Row, you can use your mouse to select the header and the new line feed.

#### 1. Reformat the text:

- Copy your file and work on the copy so you will have a backup.
- Open your file with Notepad++/ SublimeText
- Remplace every iteration of : `\r\nAddress :` by `"; "` or by `;`
  Do the same for every Header in your file.

  > the `\r\n` is because you have a line feed between company name and adress. And you want every information to be on one line.
- Add a `"` at the start and end of every line

### 2. Import in Excel.

- Copy data in Excel
- In the Data Tab > Convert

Choose:

- Delimited > Next
- Delimiter = `;`   Text indicator = `"`
- Select all your columns one by one and turn them to text!(You do not want phone number to loose leading 0)
- Finish
- Add your header

All part 2 can be useless if you save as `.csv`. I just wanted to show you the Convert Assistant. And how to handle properly adress with `;`, `'` in them and when you have data like `Fax :Mob : 12345555`. You can add escaping if you have strange data.

Disclamer:
Always work on a copy, Start all those manipulation by count `"` and `;` and other delimiter Excel could miss understand. Escape them.
Btw this is more SuperUser than SO.

### Bonus:

If you are familiar with a programation language use his buildt in String remplace to format your document in 1 sec.
with something like this:

```
        static void CSVformat() {
            string Input = 
@"Company Name

Address : XXXXXXXXX
Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567
Fax : 123456    Mob : 12345555
Web :www.www.com    E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com


Company Name

Address : XXXXXXXXX
Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567
Fax : 123456    Mob : 12345555
Web :www.www.com    E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com

Company Name

Address : XXXXXXXXX
Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567
Fax : 123456    Mob : 12345555
Web :www.www.com    E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com";
            var dd= clean(Input);            
        }

        static string clean(string s)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

            sb.Replace(
@"

Address : ", "\"; \"");
            sb.Replace(
@"
Contact : ", "\"; \"");
            sb.Replace(
@"
Fax : ", "\"; \"");
            sb.Replace(
@"
Web :", "\"; \"");

            sb.Replace(" Tel : ", "\"; \"");
            sb.Replace("    Mob : ", "\"; \"");
            sb.Replace("    E-Mail :", "\"; \"");
            sb.Replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
            sb.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
            sb.Replace("\r\n", "\"\r\n\"");

            return '"'+sb.ToString()+'"';
        }
```

Comment: Im using Sublime Text.. what is the easiest way for Add a " at the start and end of every line.. And also should i move Tel, mob, email columns down?? if so what is the easiest way? thanks for your time

Comment: Ctrl + H for search and replace.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + L, to select multiple line then press left Arrow once for start or left for end

Comment: I've Edit my post to show the final result on your Test Data.

Comment: I think that the easiest way. Tooks me 10 minute to do it with your test data and post an answer. I've selected and Replace 7 time. 8 key stroke to get start and end line delimiter

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: Working on it ;) So far so good. as soon as i finish that i will accept it. thanks alot for your time

Comment: Im sorry.. this is how i got it at the end and couldnt convert it.`"Company Name"
"Address ; xxxxxx"
"Contact ; xxxxxx"
"Tel ; xxxxxx"
"Fax ;xxxxx"
"Mob ;xxx"
"Web ;xxxxx"
"E-Mail ;xxxxx"
` is this how it is supposed to look before import it to Excel?

Comment: @stoneshak Final data should look like the one in my answer. No header to your data row. Just pure data With ; as separator.

Comment: Like : `Column1Data;Column2Data;Column3Data`

Comment: You should have more than enought information here. I don't see how i can do more without your mailling me the file. this is step by step, with explanation and even a c# working code sample.

Comment: @stoneshak, all good? you have integrate it? Any problem with Carriage return in adress, " or ;? you took the code or the Notepad way?

Comment: Thanks so much. I have used Sublime Text and edit data. Finally got the right format and it is all working fine. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following steps (only if every block have the same numer of rows).

Add a column with numbers:

```
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
|    |    A     |                   B                   |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | Column B | Column B                              |
|  2 | 1        | ompany Name                           |
|  3 | 2        |                                       |
|  4 | 3        | Address : XXXXXXXXX                   |
|  5 | 4        | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567     |
|  6 | 5        | Fax : 123456 Mob : 12345555           |
|  7 | 6        | Web :www.www.com  E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com |
|  8 |          |                                       |
|  9 |          |                                       |
| 10 | 1        | Company Name                          |
| 11 | 2        |                                       |
| 12 | 3        | Address : XXXXXXXXX                   |
| 13 | 4        | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567     |
| 14 | 5        | Fax : 123456 Mob : 12345555           |
| 15 | 6        | Web :www.www.com  E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com |
| 16 |          |                                       |
| 17 | 1        | Company Name                          |
| 18 | 2        |                                       |
| 19 | 3        | Address : XXXXXXXXX                   |
| 20 | 4        | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567     |
| 21 | 5        | Fax : 123456 Mob : 12345555           |
| 22 | 6        | Web :www.www.com E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com  |
| 23 |          |                                       |
| 24 |          | .                                     |
| 25 |          | .                                     |
| 26 |          | .                                     |
| 27 |          | .                                     |
| 28 | 1        | Company Name                          |
| 29 | 2        |                                       |
| 30 | 3        | Address : XXXXXXXXX                   |
| 31 | 4        | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567     |
| 32 | 5        | Fax : 123456 Mob : 12345555           |
| 33 | 6        | Web :www.www.com E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com  |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

consider that the best way is to numer the first block (cells A2:A7), then copy A2:A7 and filter in column B the cells that contain the company name (or those which not contains "Adress", "Contact", Fax" or "web). Paste in the column A and you'll have all the rows numbered.

Now you traspose the matrix filtering rows ID 1, 2, 3, ... and you'll find this

```
+---+--------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+
|   |      A       |          B          |                 C                 |      D       |       E        |        F         |          G          |
+---+--------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+
| 1 | ompany Name  | Address : XXXXXXXXX | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567 | Fax : 123456 | Mob : 12345555 | Web :www.www.com | E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com |
| 2 | Company Name | Address : XXXXXXXXX | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567 | Fax : 123456 | Mob : 12345555 | Web :www.www.com | E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com |
| 3 | Company Name | Address : XXXXXXXXX | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567 | Fax : 123456 | Mob : 12345555 | Web :www.www.com | E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com |
| 4 | Company Name | Address : XXXXXXXXX | Contact : XYXYXYXYX Tel : 1234567 | Fax : 123456 | Mob : 12345555 | Web :www.www.com | E-Mail :xxxx@xx.com |
+---+--------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+
```